# recover files deleted with rm command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Please if I run the command

```
#  CREATE TRASH FOLDER

if ! [ -d "$HOME/deleted" ] ; then
     mkdir $HOME/deleted
fi

TRASH=$HOME/deleted
mv $@ $TRASH
```

To move file or directory to the trash created. what is the possible command i can run to recover same file to the original directory

Comment: There is not built-in support for such an action. You might need to code a separate script for this. Also your question title says for `rm`, but the code shows `mv`? Which one are you looking for

Comment: To implement such a logic, you'd have to store the original path somewhere (maybe in the file name ?)

Comment: The command actually run like rm using the mv command. so, I have moved a file or directory to a path and i want to recover it back

Comment: seems to be an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), maybe a version control system

Comment: To emulate the trashbin behaviour on command line, you could either go with a custom script like yours or use the already existing `trash-cli` package

Answer (score 0):

If you create a deleted directory like this, you will probably get some unexpected behavior. For example:

```
rm_script test.txt
cd ../other_directory
rm_script test.txt
```

will create a single file test.txt with the content of the one in `other_dir`. Even more fun when you start rm_scripting/moving directories.

Knowing this, and referring once more to trash-cli (see comment Aserre), you might:

```
if ! [ -d "$HOME/deleted" ] ; then
    echo "What a pity! No deleted directory."
    echo "Your file(s) is/are lost forever!"
    exit 361
fi

TRASH=$HOME/deleted
for file in  $@ ; do
    if [ -f "$TRASH/$file" ] ; then
        cp "$TRASH/$file" .
    else
        echo "Hmm,.. I cannot find $file."
    fi
done
```

This also may have some unwanted results, like removing the file from one directory and un-deleting it in another.

Comment: What would cp "$TRASH/$file" if am to copy to the directory where it was formally deleted or moved

Comment: Double quote `$@` to support filenames with spaces etc.

Answer (score -3):

I just do the reverse of the same command line

```
function undo () {
  echo -n "Do you want to recover $*? "
  read ANSWER
  if [ "$ANSWER" = "y" ]; then
    mv $TRASH/$@ $PWD
    echo "$@ successfully recovered"
  else
    echo "Oops, request denied"
  fi
}
```

Comment: `$PWD` isn't right. The files could have been anywhere before they were moved. Also `$TRASH/$@` won't work if `$@` has multiple file names.

Comment: I assume the file was removed from the present directory where the same recovery command was run. will that work