# How to log and get the path of a deleted file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, logging, sh

I have a script to move files to a save folder called trash.

```
#  CREATE TRASH FOLDER

if ! [ -d "$HOME/deleted" ] ; then
     mkdir $HOME/deleted
fi

TRASH=$HOME/deleted
mv $@ $TRASH
```

How do I create a log file for the paths its deleted from and how to get the path.

Comment: How are you passing the arguments to the script. And remember `mv` does _not_ delete files in the sense you are referring to. It just moves them to another location in the disk

Comment: Can you elaborate more? It is not clear here.

Comment: Looks so similar to your older question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029467/recover-files-deleted-with-rm-command

Comment: @AbhijitPritam Pritam I have a similar script to the RM command, but here it only move to a separate location call TRASH. 

mv $@ $TRASH 2>/dev/null

when i tried to recover back, it goes to my working directory

mv "$TRASH/$file" $PWD

instead of the location it was moved from. What i want is how to get the path it was moved from and recover it back to same path.

Comment: Yes @Inian Still on the same project

Comment: Are you providing your path `$@` here? Like `mv /app/myapp/log.txt $TRASH`?

Comment: Also provide detail about `$@`. Just do `echo $@` and provide us the details.

Comment: $@ is the argument passed. so if i run my script with **saferm logo.png**,  the logo.png which is now the $@ will be moved to trash.

Comment: you can find out the full path of your argument using `readlink` and `dirname`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577093/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-directory-of-a-file-in-bash Store the result wherever you want.This allows you to specify only filename as an argument. But your solution can cause many troubles, for example when you move files of the same name from different directories. Consider another backup or file versioning system.